# Linux Kernel RSA Signature Verification crypto_akcipher_verify() output

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cryptography, rsa

I'm currently developing a kernel module where I'm performing RSA signature verification. My module is targeted at the 4.4 kernel so I decided to use the lower level `akcipher` API. I've been using the current [implementation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16-rc7/source/crypto/asymmetric_keys/public_key.c#L65) of `public_key_verify_signature` as a guide. My approach is:

1. Allocate a crypto_akcipher struct: `*tfm = crypto_alloc_akcipher("rsa", 0, 0);`
2. Allocate an akcipher_request struct: `req = akcipher_request_alloc(*tfm, GFP_KERNEL);`
3. Set the public key for the request: `err = crypto_akcipher_set_pub_key(*tfm, data, len);`
4. Place the received signature into a scatterlist and set it as an argument for the akcipher_request with: `akcipher_request_set_crypt(req, &src, &dst, sig->s_size, MAX_OUT);`
5. Finally make the call to `crypto_akcipher_verify(req)` which should calculate the expected digest
6. Compare the expected digest to the received digest to verify the signature

I'm currently at a point where I believe I'm using the API correctly but the output of `crypto_akcipher_verify` isn't conforming to the way it's used in the newer `public_key_verify_signature` example. Which is confusing me, because it seems to output part of the correct digest.

For example when a properly signed request is received I get the following results:

```
Expected Digest:
e52bed356dcbf8e4b3c1458ac3e4cb49e77512e6

Computated outbuf:
01ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff003015300906052b0e03021a05000408e52bed356dcbf8e4
```

The last 8 bytes of the computed `outbuf` is the first 8 bytes of the expected 20 byte digest. But the rest of the `outbuf` appears to be junk. (Although it is consistent every time, it's always `0x01` followed by lots of `0xffs` and finally `003015300906052b0e03021a05000408` before the last 8 bytes). Here is the chunk of code responsible for the call to `crypto_akcipher_verify(req)`:

```c
// Init completion
init_completion(&(res.completion));

// Put the data into our request structure
memcpy(inbuf, sig->s, sig->s_size);
sg_init_one(&src, inbuf, sig->s_size);
sg_init_one(&dst, outbuf, MAX_OUT);
akcipher_request_set_crypt(req, &src, &dst, sig->s_size, MAX_OUT);

// Set the completion routine callback
// results from the verify routine will be stored in &res
akcipher_request_set_callback(req, CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_BACKLOG |
                  CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_SLEEP, op_complete, &res);

// Compute the expected digest
err = wait_async_op(&res, crypto_akcipher_verify(req));

if(err) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "[!] Digest computation failed %d\n", err);
    kfree(inbuf);
    kfree(outbuf);
    return err;
}

printk(KERN_INFO "\nComputation:\n");
hexdump(outbuf, req->dst_len);

/* Do the actual verification step. */
if (req->dst_len != sig->digest_size ||
    memcmp(sig->digest, outbuf, sig->digest_size) != 0) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "[!] Signature verification failed - Key Rejected: %d\n", -EKEYREJECTED);
    printk(KERN_INFO "[!] Sig len: %d   Computed len: %d\n", sig->digest_size, req->dst_len);
    kfree(inbuf);
    kfree(outbuf);
    return -EKEYREJECTED;
}
```

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated. Sorry if this post isn't extremely concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've performed raw or textbook RSA decryption. What you are looking at is the hash + a padding known as PKCS#1 v1.5. This is also defined in PKCS#1 v2.0 onwards for backwards compatibility (it is still considered secure, even though it is deterministic).

So have a look at [PKCS#1 v2.2, 8.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2.2) step 3, where it is explained that you have to build the same structure yourself and then compare. Note that [9.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2) contains some helpful shortcut for creating the structures *in the notes*.

Finally: SHA-1 is not considered secure anymore for signature generation / verification. Upgrade ASAP!

Comment: Sorry, missed this question for some reason or other. I'm not so well known to kernel level development which could have made me skip the question...

Comment: @Marteen Thank you! Let me take a look at this. I knew there was something I was missing because the hex dump was consistent and looked like a struct of some kind. Let me take a look! I'll post back with my code when I figure it out

Comment: Don't forget to check if there is already something there to perform the unpadding, the padding is quite standard :)

Comment: Thanks again! Not sure I would have realized this without you, appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1):

As @Maarten suggested above. What I was seeing was the PKCS1 v1.5 encoding. From the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2), the padding looks like:

```
EM = 0x00 || 0x01 || PS || 0x00 || T.
```

Where PS is:

"PS consisting of emLen - tLen - 3 octets with hexadecimal value 0xff.  The length of PS will be at least 8 octets."

And the DER encoding "T" at the end for SHA1 is (I'll switch to SHA256 as suggested above):

```
SHA-1:   (0x)30 21 30 09 06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00 04 14 || H.
```

The best way to parse this padding in newer kernels is using the `"pkcs1pad(rsa,SHA256)"` type when calling `crypto_alloc_akcipher`. Then `rsa_verify` will parse the padding for you. Unfortunately since I'm trying to port this across a few kernel versions I had to look at an older method and [referenced the old `rsa_verify` routine](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/db6c43bd2132dc2dd63d73a6d1ed601cffd0ae06/crypto/asymmetric_keys/rsa.c#L101).

In the end my SHA256 EMSA PKCS#1 v1.5 parsing code looks like:

```
static const u8 RSA_digest_info_SHA256[] = {
    0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09,
    0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01,
    0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20
};

typedef struct RSA_ASN1_template {
    const u8 * data;
    size_t size;
} RSA_ASN1_template;

RSA_ASN1_template sha256_template;

// Derived from https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/db6c43bd2132dc2dd63d73a6d1ed601cffd0ae06/crypto/asymmetric_keys/rsa.c#L101
// and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2
// thanks to Maarten Bodewes for answering the question on Stackoverflow
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662595/linux-kernel-rsa-signature-verification-crypto-akcipher-verify-output
static char *pkcs_1_v1_5_decode_emsa(unsigned char * EM,
                        unsigned long  EMlen,
                        const u8 * asn1_template,
                        size_t asn1_size,
                        size_t hash_size) {

    unsigned int t_offset, ps_end, ps_start, i;

    if (EMlen < 2 + 1 + asn1_size + hash_size)
        return NULL;    

/* Decode the EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5
 * note: leading zeros are stripped by the RSA implementation in older kernels
 * so   EM = 0x00 || 0x01 || PS || 0x00 || T
 * will become EM = 0x01 || PS || 0x00 || T.
 */
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(4,8,0)
    ps_start = 1;
    if (EM[0] != 0x01) {
        printk(" = -EBADMSG [EM[0] == %02u]", EM[0]);
        return NULL;
    }
#else
    ps_start = 2;
    if (EM[0] != 0x00 || EM[1] != 0x01) {
        printk(" = -EBADMSG [EM[0] == %02u] [EM[1] == %02u]", EM[0], EM[1]);
        return NULL;
    }
#endif

    // Calculate offsets
    t_offset = EMlen - (asn1_size + hash_size);
    ps_end = t_offset - 1;

    // Check if there's a 0x00 seperator between PS and T
    if (EM[ps_end] != 0x00) {
        printk(" = -EBADMSG [EM[T-1] == %02u]", EM[ps_end]);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Check the PS 0xff padding 
    for (i = ps_start; i < ps_end; i++) {
        if (EM[i] != 0xff) {
            printk(" = -EBADMSG [EM[PS%x] == %02u]", i - 2, EM[i]);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    // Compare the DER encoding T of the DigestInfo value
    if (crypto_memneq(asn1_template, EM + t_offset, asn1_size) != 0) {
        printk(" = -EBADMSG [EM[T] ASN.1 mismatch]");
        return NULL;
    }

    return EM + t_offset + asn1_size;

}
```

And the verification function that calls it:

```
// Verify a recieved signature
int verify_sig_rsa(akcipher_request * req, pkey_signature * sig) {

    int err;
    void *inbuf, *outbuf, *result = NULL;
    op_result res;
    struct scatterlist src, dst;
    crypto_akcipher *tfm = crypto_akcipher_reqtfm(req);
    int MAX_OUT = crypto_akcipher_maxsize(tfm);


    inbuf = kzalloc(PAGE_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);

    err = -ENOMEM;
    if(!inbuf) {
        return err;
    }

    outbuf = kzalloc(MAX_OUT, GFP_KERNEL);

    if(!outbuf) {
        kfree(inbuf);
        return err;
    } 

    // Init completion
    init_completion(&(res.completion));

    // Put the data into our request structure
    memcpy(inbuf, sig->s, sig->s_size);
    sg_init_one(&src, inbuf, sig->s_size);
    sg_init_one(&dst, outbuf, MAX_OUT);
    akcipher_request_set_crypt(req, &src, &dst, sig->s_size, MAX_OUT);

    // Set the completion routine callback
    // results from the verify routine will be stored in &res
    akcipher_request_set_callback(req, CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_BACKLOG |
                  CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_SLEEP, op_complete, &res);

    // Compute the expected digest
    err = wait_async_op(&res, crypto_akcipher_verify(req));

    if(err) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "[!] Digest computation failed %d\n", err);
        kfree(inbuf);
        kfree(outbuf);
        kfree(result);
        return err;
    }

    // Decode the PKCS#1 v1.5 encoding
    sha256_template.data = RSA_digest_info_SHA256;
    sha256_template.size = ARRAY_SIZE(RSA_digest_info_SHA256);
    result = pkcs_1_v1_5_decode_emsa(outbuf, req->dst_len, 
             sha256_template.data, sha256_template.size, 32);

    err = -EINVAL;
    if(!result) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "[!] EMSA PKCS#1 v1.5 decode failed\n");
        kfree(inbuf);
        kfree(outbuf);
        return err;
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "\nComputation:\n");
    hexdump(result, 20); 

    /* Do the actual verification step. */
    if (crypto_memneq(sig->digest, result, sig->digest_size) != 0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "[!] Signature verification failed - Key Rejected: %d\n", -EKEYREJECTED);
        kfree(inbuf);
        kfree(outbuf);
        return -EKEYREJECTED;
    }
    
    printk(KERN_INFO "[+] RSA signature verification passed\n");
    kfree(inbuf);
    kfree(outbuf);
    return 0;
}
```

If anybody wants to reference the complete code, it [can be found here](https://github.com/landhb/Trigger/blob/master/kernel/xt_crypto.c).